# Hi I’ve just replaced my 207 drivers door lock and now when I close the door all the locks lock unlock 3 times and the remote and keys do not lock

Tags: locks, peugeot, peugeot-207

I’ve recently changed my drivers door lock on a 3 door 207 and when I try to lock with remote it one nothing when I use the key it locks and unlocks 3 time and then stays unlocked i’ve tried the ignition for 10 second method and still dose not work dose it matter the lock came out of a 5 door hath……………tia

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is the "207" a Peugeot? What part of the lock did you replace? The keyed portion or the mechanism which latches the door?

Comment: Was the lock identical to the original? Were the wires in the same positions?

Comment: I’m not sure the replacement was from a 5 door are they different cheers

Comment: Well, you have the old one and the new one - did you check?

Comment: Can you put the old lock back in temporarily, and see if the problem goes away?  Sounds like wiring is connected wrong, or the whole key unit is significantly different.

Comment: Threw the old one away but keys are ok it only started when I put the other lock in cheers